# If else statement using "System.Convert.ToInt32" not working

Tags: c#, .net, string, if-statement, int32

I am trying to display a particular string using an if else statement based on the value of a date/time object.

I am using a formula editor which checks for syntax and I get no problems, however when the formulas is parsed in the application I get blanks where the condition should be met.

Here is my formula:

```
if (System.Convert.ToInt32(rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.DateDied"].Value)>0)
{
 return System.Convert.ToString(rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.FirstName"].Value) + " " + System.Convert.ToString(rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.LastName"].Value) + '\n' + "Deceased: " + System.String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.DateDied"].Value);
}
else
{
  return System.Convert.ToString(rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.FirstName"].Value) + " " + System.Convert.ToString(rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.LastName"].Value);
 }
```

The Formula editor allows conversion to different data types and I've tried revising the formula with the returned value as Boolean but this doesn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: Omg stop doing everything in one line, then use a debugger, and use `int.TryParse();`

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a date to int?

Answer (score 4):

Convert.ToInt32 method doesn't support the conversion from DateTime to int.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_DateTime_

Comment: Yes I have seen this but wasn't sure if there was a way around it

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

// ListFields();

try
{
if (System.Convert.ToInt32(System.String.Format("{0:yyyy}",rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.DateDied"].Value))>1)
return "Deceased date: " +  System.String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.DateDied"].Value);
}

catch(System.Exception e)

{
System.String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",rpt.Fields["AppointmentResourceLink.Appointment.Patient.DateDied"].Value);
}

return "";